# Is there shorter way to work with dotnetnuke and SVN

Tags: asp.net, svn, debugging, tortoisesvn, dotnetnuke

I have one project with a few sub projects in it. A few projects contain dotnetnuke modules. And I have committed this project to SVN repo. But now when I checkout version from SVN I have to manually copy module project to dotnetnuke/desktopModules directory. I am trying to find some shorter way for this :(

I follow solution from this question [DotNetNuke and Subversion guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478798/dotnetnuke-and-subversion-guidelines) , but have no luck. I added nant.build file to my project with dotnetnuke modules. Navigate to it from command line and run 'nant' command, but I got following error :(

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeInitializationException:
>   The type initializer fo r
>   'NAnt.Console.ConsoleStub' threw an
>   exception. --->
>   System.Security.SecurityEx ception:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOP
>   ermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c5619 34e089'
>   failed.    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMa rk& stackMark,
>   Boolean isPermSet)    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, S tackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
>   at
>   System.AppDomainSetup.VerifyDir(String
>   dir, Boolean normalize)    at
>   System.AppDomain.get_BaseDirectory()
>   at
>   log4net.Config.XmlConfiguratorAttribute.Configure(Assembly
>   sourceAssembly,  ILoggerRepository
>   targetRepository)    at
>   log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.ConfigureRepository(Assembly
>   assemb ly, ILoggerRepository
>   repository)    at
>   log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(Assembly
>   repositor yAssembly, Type
>   repositoryType, String repositoryName,
>   Boolean readAssemblyAttri butes)    at
>   log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(Assembly
>   repositor yAssembly, Type
>   repositoryType)    at
>   log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.GetRepository(Assembly
>   repositoryAs sembly)    at
>   log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetLogger(Assembly
>   repositoryAssembly, String n ame)
>   at
>   log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly
>   repositoryAssembly, String name)    at
>   log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Type
>   type)    at
>   NAnt.Console.ConsoleStub..cctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at NAnt.Console.ConsoleStub.Main(String[]
>   args)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your first point, if you map your source control repository directly to your website's desktopmodules folder, you won't need to copy it manually after getting latest.

For the second point, you may need to [unblock the files being used by NAnt](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2011/01/19/Nant-Build-Error-SystemSecurityPermissionsFileIOPermission.aspx) or look into [using a different version of NAnt that does not have this issue](http://old.nabble.com/nant-0.91-alpha1-Build---Windows-7-2008-td28897200.html). Alternatively, you can look into [using MSBuild scripts instead of NAnt](http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I can confirm that the 0.91 alphas don't have the `FileIOPermission` issue.